# inserting data sequentially into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to insert sequential numbers into a single column.

The columns have been set to NULL

Is there a command I can now use to populate just that column with sequential numbers

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number` analytic function to generate sequence number, that can be used to update the values.

```
 WITH cte
 AS
 ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT null)) as rn , column1
   FROM table1
 )
 UPDATE cte
 SET column1 = rn
```

Comment: that almost did it but it would be nice if we can get it to sequence properly for instance like 0000001, 0000002,0000003 etc up to 7 characters

Comment: @khan16, i didn't get it, can you elaborate?

Comment: the results set looks like this for now 1 10 100 1000  10000 10001 10002 10003 etc

Comment: @khan16, can you edit the question to include the current values and expected values.

Comment: current values are 1 10 100 1000 10000 10001 10002 10003 expected values are 0000001, 0000002, 0000003,0000004 etc

Comment: @khan16 If you want numbers how does "0000001" make sense? Don't store numbers with leading 0's it is pointless and makes everything harder to work with. If you really want such silly formatting do that when you pull the data out instead of messing up your data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> that almost did it but it would be nice if we can get it to sequence
>   properly for instance like 0000001, 0000002,0000003 etc up to 7
>   characters

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME)), 7) AS ROW_NUM
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Update after comment:

> Basically this is what I am trying to do. I will be running a query to
>   grab those 7 character ID from that ALTATH column that will be used as
>   Reference ID so the column should have those output or type in
>   it..hope that's clear...thanks

I would personally use an Identity column and format the output when selecting records like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID_COLUMN), 7) AS ROW_NUM
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

If you use the analytical functions the ROW_NUM column will not be the same everytime.  If you use Identity SQL Server will take care of assigning the numbers in sequence for you.  That is the DBMS's job.

Comment: exactly what I wanted....now how do I get that to populate the column or is it already populated with the result

Comment: Is this an existing table you are trying to update this one time or are you trying to assign Id's for each transaction this way?

Comment: this is an existing table and I want to be able to save or have that output in that ALTATH column for query purposes...thanks

Comment: Basically this is what I am trying to do. I will be running a query to grab those 7 character ID from that ALTATH column that will be used as Reference ID so the column should have those output or type in it..hope that's clear...thanks